# Handsontable: When scroll vertically up and down, I got the css style removed

Tags: handsontable

I am using a handsontable, I customize the error in cells.

```
var cell = hot.getCell(rowKey, id);
$(cell).css('background-color', '#ff4c42');
$(cell).text(message);
$(cell).css('color', 'white');
```

Now when I scroll up and down and cells with error style disappeared, when I scroll to them again the style disappeared!

Comment: same issue please need help

Comment: Any example with jsfiddle ?

Comment: when I press validate-> the error appear, try to scroll down, the styling of error disappear!
http://jsfiddle.net/96j6r9mz/10/

Answer (score 0):

I made this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/car3673r/) for you.

```
afterValidate: function(isValid, value, row, prop, source) {
  if (row == 2 && hot.propToCol(prop) == 2) {
    hot.setDataAtCell(row, hot.propToCol(prop), 'error');
  }
},
invalidCellClassName: 'myInvalidClass',
```

You need to declare a validator and set a invalidClass in your css.

You can't update the css with your method because the Handsontable settings doesn't have this parameters and when you scroll, it re-render the table and "delete" your changes.

Comment: Can you tell me if I can have multi validators for one feild. like empty validator, size validator....

Comment: No but you can create a global validator and call `this`in the validator to get informations like `row` or `prop`.